# flatsome menu responsiveness breakpoint

Tags: css, wordpress, breakpoints, responsiveness

my website's main menu responsive breakpoint is at the 850px for mobile menu. Though I want to change it to a mobile menu from 1369px, as the desktop main menu after 1369px overflow the site content. I have tried CSS such as:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1369px) {
    .header-nav.header-nav-main.nav.nav-left.nav-line-grow.nav-size-small.nav-spacing-medium.nav-uppercase {
        display: none;
    }
    .mobile-nav.nav.nav-left {
        display: block; !important:
    }
}
```

Thus it only hides desktop menu but no hamburger menu appears...

Could somebody advise me how to change this breakpoint correctly? p.s. I am an amateur beginner in web development.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Good if you found a solution. In general I strongly recommend to go with the options that the theme offers through the admin UI, WP hooks and template hierarchy. Overriding the breakpoints for a few components won't typically end well. `flatsome.css` alone has 71 media queries with different screen sizes targeting different UI components. All those rules are compatible with each others in all kinds of different combinations and scenarios. By overriding some breakpoints for a few elements, you end up with a UI that is incompatible with the theme it's been built on. (which is not nice)

Answer (score 0):

you may add another breakpoint to your css file easily by adding @media :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1369px) {
    .header-nav, .header-nav-main, .nav, .nav-left, .nav-line-grow, .nav-size-small, .nav-spacing-medium, .nav-uppercase {
        display: none;
    }
    .mobile-nav, .nav.nav-left {
        display: block; !important:
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but it's parent container is also set to display: none, so you'll want to target that instead.

Something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1369px) {
    .header-inner .flex-col.show-for-medium.flex-left {
        display: flex;
        /* block will work too, but flex is most likely its default state, up to you really */
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Firefox' Inspector, showing the mobile nav's parent element, .flex-col.flex-left, set to display: none;]

Answer (score 0):

I use this code, just change max-width: 1369px to your breakpoint

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1369px) {
    .header-inner .flex-col.show-for-medium.flex-left {
        display: flex !important;
    }
    .hide-for-medium {
    display: none !important;
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: I use with flasome 3.15.7